# Silverlight Web Application RichTextBox adding intellisense capability

Tags: silverlight, events, richtextbox, textinput

I was trying to add intellisense capability. I need to handle TextInput event in RTB but seems not to be fired

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded" TextInput="LayoutRoot_TextInput">
    <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,18,0,0" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="177" Width="309" 
                 TextInputUpdate="richTextBox1_TextInputUpdate_1" TextInput="richTextBox1_TextInput_2" />
</Grid>
```

i have a break point also i hv written console.writline statement to verify the code workds or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `PreviewTextInput`, or create a new control that inherits from `PreviewTextInput` and then override the `PreviewTextInput`-method in the derived class.